# Salesforce2Salesforce testclass help

Tags: unit-test, salesforce2salesforce

I have batch class that publishes the opportunities to other Salesforce Org for shared accounts.
In testclass, I create an account and insert the accountid in NetworkConnectionPartner record.  Call the batch class. It fails to insert the opportunity in the batch class because  account  status is still ‘Invite’. It throws the message – ‘INVALID_PARTNER_NETWORK_STATUS’.

I have searched for many online materials.. Not found any answer that heps me..

Any help will be higly appreciated.

Test class is below:

```
@istest
public class OpportunityPublishtoConnectionOTP_Test {
    static testmethod void OpppublishOTP(){

        account.Name = 'TEST ACCOUNT';
        account.BillingStreet = 'Test Street';
        account.BillingCity = 'Test City';
        account.BillingCountry = 'US';
        account.Billingstate = 'Alabama';
        insert account;

     test.starttest();

        Id networkId = ConnectionHelper.getConnectionId('Adheris Health');
        system.debug('networkid:'+ networkid);
        PartnerNetworkRecordConnection conrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();

        conrecord.ConnectionId = networkid;
        conrecord.LocalRecordId = account.id;  
        conrecord.SendClosedTasks = false;
        conrecord.SendOpenTasks = false;
        conrecord.SendEmails = false;   
        insert conrecord; 

     test.stoptest();   
        system.debug('Connrection record:' + conrecord);


          OpportunityPublishtoConnectionOTProcess OpppublishOTP = new OpportunityPublishtoConnectionOTProcess();

            id JOBID = database.executeBatch(OpppublishOTP, 200);
```

}

**Batch class:**

```
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) 
{
    List<PartnerNetworkConnection> PNetworkList = new List<PartnerNetworkConnection>([select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection
    where ConnectionStatus = 'Accepted' AND ConnectionName = 'XYZ']);

    ID NetworkId = PNetworkList[0].ID;

    Set<ID> AccountIDs = new Set<ID>();
    Set<ID> SharedAccountIds = new Set<ID>();
    for(sObject s : Scope) 
    {    
        Account act = (Account)s;
        AccountIDs.add(act.id);    
    }   


    If(AccountIds.size()>0)
    {
        For(PartnerNetworkRecordConnection SharedAcc : [SELECT Status, LocalRecordId, ConnectionId FROM 
                                                        PartnerNetworkRecordConnection WHERE LocalRecordId IN :AccountIds ])

        {
            system.debug('SharedAccount status:' + SharedAcc.status);

            If((SharedAcc.status.equalsignorecase('Received') ||  SharedAcc.status.equalsignorecase('Sent') || SharedAcc.status.equalsignorecase('Invite')) &&   SharedAcc.ConnectionId == NetworkId ) 
                {
                    SharedAccountIds.add(sharedAcc.LocalRecordId);
                }

        }
    }


    List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection> conrecordlist = new List<PartnerNetworkRecordConnection>();

    for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT ID, AccountID FROM OPPORTUNITY WHERE Opportunity_BU2__c = 'Adheris Health' AND AccountId IN :SharedAccountIds])
    {
        PartnerNetworkRecordConnection conrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();

        conrecord.ConnectionId = NetworkId;
        conrecord.LocalRecordId = opp.Id;  
        conrecord.RelatedRecords = 'Opportunity_Drug__c'; 
        conrecord.SendClosedTasks = false;
        conrecord.SendOpenTasks = false;
        conrecord.SendEmails = false;  
        conrecord.ParentRecordId = Opp.AccountId;
         conrecordlist.add(conrecord);   

    } 

    Opportunityprocessed = string.valueof(conrecordlist.size());
    insert conrecordlist;
    system.debug(' Number of Opportunity shared:' + Opportunityprocessed);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent quite a bit of time on this when I was building an S2SService and looked at my notes (as of V32) - some of which may be relevant to you:

1. You can't mock `PartnerNetworkConnection` in a testMethod. Not with DML, not with Test.loadData.  However, `PartnerNetworkConnection` is accessible to testmethods, even with `SeeAllData=false`.  I ended up just using the first accepted PNC (of course, that meant my sandboxes had to have an accepted PNC before the testmethod would run - you'll thus need two sandboxes with an S2S connection between them; when you deploy to PROD, you'll need a connection between PROD and a Dev Edition org to make the testmethod run
2. `PartnerNetworkRecordConnection` can be created as part of the test. Unfortunately, it is impossible to force the Status to `Sent`. Not with DML, not with `test.loadData()`, not by checking after `test.stopTest()`.
3. Any inserted PNRC will get a status of `Invite`, but, because we are in a testmethod, SFDC doesn't forward to the target system which is how the status changes to `Sent`.
4. if we try and insert a PNRC whose parentId has not yet been accepted in the target system, the insert fails with an invalid Status error. Thus, inserting PNRCs for Opportunities that depend on the Account being Sent won't work in a testmethod. Thus, it is impossible without `SeeAllData=true` (and then we'd have to have an existing parent already accepted) to insert a PNRC for a child referring to a parent

More [S2S items of interest can be found on my blog](http://cropredysfdc.com/2014/11/17/s2s-salesforce-to-salesforce-adventures/).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, is failing because the connection status is not active. You will need to either make sure the connection has been accepted(which will be a problem in sandboxes) and rely on that on your test or don't test that part and adjust your test so that it doesn't fail if your connection is not active.