# Test class failure on Case Object

Tags: apex, code-coverage, failing-tests, case-object

I'm blocked in creating a Record for **PartnerNetworkConnection**.I'm getting an error like

> **QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**.
>   **Stack Trace:** Class.caseForward.forward: line 30, column 1
>   Class.caseForwardTest.testMethod1: line 26, column 1

**In apex class:**

I'm getting query exception in below line

> PartnerNetworkConnection con = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection where ConnectionName='Penson Worldwide' and ConnectionStatus='Accepted' limit 1];

Not sure how to cover this in the test class.Can someone help me on this asap.

Thanks in advance....

**Apex class:**

```
public class caseForward{

    public Case caseObj{get; set;}
    public Case currentCase{get;set;}

    public caseForward(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        Id caseId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        currentCase = [SELECT Initial_Request_to_Penson__c FROM case WHERE id = :caseId];
        caseObj=(Case) controller.getRecord();
    }

    public PageReference forward(){ 

        if (currentCase.Initial_Request_to_Penson__c == null || currentCase.Initial_Request_to_Penson__c.trim().length() == 0)
        {
            system.debug('Initial_Request_to_Penson__c::::::'+currentCase.Initial_Request_to_Penson__c);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Initial Request to Penson" field is required!'));
            return null;
        }

        //Case currentCase;

        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();

        try
        {           
            PartnerNetworkConnection con = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName from PartnerNetworkConnection where ConnectionName='Penson Worldwide' and ConnectionStatus='Accepted' limit 1];
            PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();
            newrecord.ConnectionId = con.Id;
            newrecord.LocalRecordId = caseObj.Id;  
            newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'CaseComment,Attachment';
            newrecord.SendClosedTasks = true;
            newrecord.SendOpenTasks = true;
            newrecord.SendEmails = true;   
            System.Debug('@@@@@@ 1'+newrecord.id);
            insert newrecord;


            System.Debug('@@@@@@@ 2'+newrecord.id);        
            caseObj.Status ='Sent To Penson';
            caseObj.Sent_To_Penson__c = true;
            update caseObj;
            System.Debug(+newrecord.id);
            Pagereference casePage=new Pagereference ('/'+caseObj.id+'?error=1');
            return casePage;
        }
        Catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Unable to forward case.  Error: ' + e.getMessage()));
            throw e;    
            Database.rollback(sp);
            return null;
        }
  }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@isTest (seealldata = true)
private class caseForwardTest {

    private static testMethod void testMethod1() {

        //Case
        Case cas = new Case(Status ='New', Priority = 'Medium', Origin = 'Email');
        insert cas;

        Test.startTest();

        PageReference pageRef = Page.CaseForwordPage;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',cas.Id);

        caseForward objcaseForward = new caseForward(new ApexPages.StandardController(cas));        
        objcaseForward.forward();

        cas.Initial_Request_to_Penson__c = 'This is a test class request to pension'; 
        update cas;

        objcaseForward = new caseForward(new ApexPages.StandardController(cas));        
        objcaseForward.forward();       

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting error during deployment or in normal execution?

Comment: have a look into this ans http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/98885/salesforce2salesforce-testclass-help

Comment: `PartnerNetworkConnection` can't be mocked by DML, it is part of org data (and hence `seeAlldata=true` is unnecessary).  This means in every environment there has to be a valid PNC given the way you coded this.  The answer that @SantanuBoral pointed to is one way of addressing this

Comment: @SantanuBoral When I'm executing my testclass I'm getting this error and my test's are failing with the Queryexception when I'm retrieving PartnerNetworkConnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting QueryException as the query doesn't return a record and you are trying to assign directly to the object.

To eliminate this issue do this changes before using PartnerNetworkConnection object:

```
PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();
            PartnerNetworkConnection con = new PartnerNetworkConnection();

            if(!Test.isRunningTest())
            {
                List<PartnerNetworkConnection>  lstCon = [select Id, ConnectionStatus, ConnectionName 
                    from PartnerNetworkConnection 
                    where ConnectionName='Penson Worldwide' 
                    and ConnectionStatus='Accepted' 
                    limit 1]; 
                    if(!lstCon.isEmpty())
                    {
                        con = lstCon[0];
                        newrecord.ConnectionId = con.Id;
                        newrecord.LocalRecordId = caseObj.Id;  
                        newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'CaseComment,Attachment';
                        newrecord.SendClosedTasks = true;
                        newrecord.SendOpenTasks = true;
                        newrecord.SendEmails = true;   
                        System.Debug('@@@@@@ 1'+newrecord.id);
                        insert newrecord;
                        System.Debug('@@@@@@@ 2'+newrecord.id);   
                    }

            }

            caseObj.Status ='Sent To Penson';
            caseObj.Sent_To_Penson__c = true;
            update caseObj;
            System.Debug(+newrecord.id);
            Pagereference casePage=new Pagereference ('/'+caseObj.id+'?error=1');
            return casePage;
```

Secondly, DML operation is not allowed on `PartnerNetworkConnection` object. So we cannot mock PartnerNetworkConnection record.

Also using `Test.isRunningTest()` in apex class will help you which piece of code to be executed during testing or in normal execution.

*I have tried to show an example, you can change at your own purpose.*

Comment: You can first close this question and ask a new one

Comment: I have updated with above lines but now I have less code coverage below the threshold so how to overcome with this issue?

Comment: You just create the record at your org to satisfy the SOQL query